# Prometheus Alertmanager - What does cluster status "disabled" mean?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, prometheus-alertmanager, kube-prometheus-stack

I am using `kube-prometheus-stack`, deployed via Helm to my K8s cluster. This incudes the Prometheus Alertmanager among others. I'm trying to configure it to send alert notifications to Slack and am running into some problems.

When I go to the Alertmanager page and select the Status tab, it shows that it's up, but that the cluster status is disabled.

What does that mean? Does it need to enabled for it to be able to send notifications? If so, how do I enable it? Keep in mind I am using Helm, so I affect configuration via the chart's values.yaml file.

Comment: I configured the alertmanager some time go in Helm and had the same doubt. Anyway, the cluster status was not relevant to properly set up alerts receivers.
If you have any issue, check the log of the prometheus operator and alert manager pods.